# how to skip records that are not delimited separated in R

Tags: r

I am having a data set (about 500,000 rows * 20 cols). most of the rows are separated by space, but there are some outliers are not (bad records I guess). I am trying to load the data into R using `fread()`, but it always throws an error at me because there are rows that are not separated -

error message -

> Expected sep (' ') but '
>   ' ends field 1 on line 247172 when detecting types: 1128=99=55035=d49=CME34=410252=2014121417033281615=USD22=848=120255=HI107=LAXX9-MIAX9200=201911202=0207=XCME461=FMAXSX462=2555=2600=[N/A]602=354603=8623=1624=1600=[N/A]602=222603=8623=1624=2562=1731=1762=IS827=2864=2865=5866=201411241145=223000000865=7866=201911251145=200000000870=5871=24872=1871=24872=3871=24872=4871=24872=11871=24872=14947=USD969=20996=CTRCT1140=9991141=21022=GBX264=51022=GBI264=21142=T1143=4001144=31146=01147=01150=37801151=LAX1180=131300=705796=201412129787=0.019850=010=101

Is there a way to skip these records?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the  `nrows` and `skip` arguments?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a particularly huge file. Try something along these lines:

```
table( count.fields("path/to/file/filename.txt", quote="", sep=" ") )
```

This will tabulate the number of "deformed lines". If they are not too frequent, then you should just edit with an ordinary text editor. If a pure R solution is needed then use `readLines` to bring into the R workspace and `gregexpr` to count spaces in each line.